# template self friendship

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
template < typename T >
struct test
{
  template < typename U >
  friend struct test<U>;
};

int main() {}
```

This is perfectly valid code, no?  I ask because MSVC++ 2010 fails to compile it.  Not the first time templates have confuzled the MS compiler though.  As far as I can tell from books, websites, and such it should work.

Comment: comeau fails to compile it too and says 
`'MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions "ComeauTest.c", line 5: error: a friend declaration may not declare a partial specialization friend struct test<U>; '`

Comment: nevermind.  I'm a f'n retard.  MSVC is right, just not very helpful.

Comment: Explain your findings and solution, for future reference. :)

Comment: Leave out the <U>.  Compiler thinks you're trying to specialize with it.

Comment: I'd move that to an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
template < typename T >
struct test
{
  template < typename U >
  friend struct test; // no <U>
};

int main() {}
```