# Template class friendship

Tags: c++, friend, access-control

I recently came across a c++ piece of code where a class is made friend to itself. As I have read on different forums a class is already a friend to itself. So I was wondering if there is a specific reason why one would want to make a class friend to itself explicitly.

Another question would be, what's the reason in making a class a friend of itself?

Maybe someone with a lot of experience can clarify this topic.

Here is the code example, to illustrate my question:

```
template < typename T>
class Foo: public T
{
protected:
   template < typename U>
   friend class Foo;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? I can see no purpose (class can already access its own private/protected members, no need for frending self).

Comment: The class being friend to itself is pointless, it would allow the access of private fields which are accessible by the class anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access private elements of object of same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832613/access-private-elements-of-object-of-same-class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a class friend itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686342/making-a-class-friend-itself)

Comment: Might have left after refactoring

Comment: The only reasons I can think of are 1) you don't want to spend time on a special case in a code generator, so it will show up in the generated code, or 2) stale code left over from a refactoring, where nobody noticed because the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: @molbdnilo I bet it fall in either. You cannot be that incompetent.

Comment: "I have read on different forums a class is already a friend to itself."  This is false.

Comment: It is not a friend of itself. Any template instantiation of `Foo` will be a friend of any other one. The crucial detail is that a class template is not a type.

Comment: @JohnDibling, can you explain why it is false?

Comment: @AlexandraC:  Because it simply isn't true that a class is a friend of itself.  These forums you've been reading might be trying to conflate a friendship relationship with access to the class' `private` members, and while it's true that establishing a friendship relationship does grant this access, that doesn't mean that a class is a friend of itself.

Comment: @JohnDibling, that sounds perfectly logic. +1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no point indeed to make a class a friend to itself, except if it is a template class. For example the following code makes sense:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    template<class U>
    friend class A;
}
```

An STL example is the `std::_Ptr_base` which is the base class for `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Templates are a nice observation, since templated classes are different types themselves. However I can't think of a scenario where one template has access to something another template does not.

Comment: `std::_Ptr_base` is an implementation detail, not part of the standard. And none of those three have anything to do with the STL.

Comment: @chris, I'm not sure what you mean. STL stands for Standard Template Library and the smart pointers are, as far as I know, part of the STL for C++11. Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @rashmatash, You might read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about)

Comment: OK thanks. I was reading Stroustrup's book the other day where it implied that the smart pointers where part of standard library. Anyway, I don't see how it would matter for the example at hand.

Comment: @rashmatash, Well, smart pointers are certainly part of the standard library, but the standard library is part of standard C++, and it includes both things like smart pointers and the sections heavily influenced by the STL like containers. The STL existed before C++ was even standardized. Thinking the STL is a subset of the standard library isn't quite correct and won't always work, but it's pretty close.

Comment: @chris, I wasn't quite aware of this distinction. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm working on a matrix lib and `matrix<T>` needs friend access to `matrix<bool>` in `matrix<T>::operator==`

Answer (score 5):

It is not making the class a friend of itself, it is making all classes of that template a friend to all others. So `A<Foo>` is a friend of `A<Bar>` which is a different class.

I am surprised the syntax is as you print it and not `template<typename U> friend class A<U>;` but that is what it actually means.

Comment: `template<typename U> friend class A<U>;` because it is incorrect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313354/template-self-friendship

Comment: Yes that is the syntax and it's how you create a class but how would it work if my template takes 2 parameters and I want to use one of them in the friendship, so I have class Foo< A, B > and I want to make class Foo< A, anything_else > a friend not Foo types that have a different first template parameter